# Does assigning an object to another mean that instant variables will aslo change?

Tags: java, oop, pass-by-reference

I am trying to to create a `stacks` which has the following API:

```
Stacks(int n)// creates stacks of size n

pop() //returns the last element pushed in the stacks 

pop(int n) //returns an array of of n elements 

push(int e) //appends an element to the stacks

push(int n, ar[]) //appends an array to the stack
```

The stacks should be able to dynamically change size when needed, so client programs dont have to do it every time.

I have done all that only my problem is when assigning object `A` to object `B` doesn't that mean that `A` will now points to the address of `B`?

Here is my code and i hope it explaines what i mean

```
public class Stacks {
    /*
     * constructs a stack object
     * @param n that will determine that size of the stacks to be constructed
     */
    public Stacks(int n)
    {
        this.elemetns= new int[n];
        this.size=n;
        this.top=-1;
    }
    /*
     * constructs a stack object, with size of 2 when no parameter is given
     */
    public Stacks()
    {
        this.elemetns= new int[2];
        this.size=2;
        this.top=-1;
    }

    public int pop()
    {
        if (top<0)
        {
            System.out.println("Error code 2: Empty stacks");
            return -1;
        }
        else
            {
                int n= this.elemetns[top];
                top--;
                return n;
            }
    }
    public int [] pop(int size)
    {
        if (this.size<size)
        {
            System.out.println("Error code 3: The Maximum number of elements that can be acquired is "+ this.size);
            return null;
        }
        else 
        {
            int res[]= new int[size];
            for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
            {
                res[i]=pop();
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
    public void push(int e)
    {
        if (!isFull())
        {
            this.elemetns[++top]=e;
            System.out.println(e+" has been pushed to the stack ");
        }
        else
        {
            updateStacksSize(this);
            this.elemetns[++top]=e;
            System.out.println(e+" has been pushed to the stack ");
        }

    }
    public void push(int n,int [] ar)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
            this.push(ar[i]);
    }
    private void updateStacksSize(Stacks s)
    {
        int newSize= s.top*2;
        Stacks newStacks= new Stacks(newSize);
        for (int i = s.top; i>-1;i--)
            newStacks.elemetns[i]=s.pop();
        s= newStacks;//shouldnt newStacks get garbage collected
//and s gets the new address and attributes of  newStacks?

    }
    private boolean isFull(){return this.size==(this.top+1);}



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Stacks s= new Stacks(5);
        for (int i=0;i<7;i++)
            s.push(i+1);
        System.out.println();
        int []arr= s.pop(6);
        for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    private int elemetns[];
    private int top;
    private int size;
}
```

Why does running this program results in problem with the old size although the current object's has been updated.

one more question is it possible to assign `this= newStacks` instead of instantiating new `Stacks object`

Comment: No assigning `this` is not possible in Java. `this` is assigned only once, by JVM, and it is effectively final variable of an object.

Comment: You assign to a local variable / argument, that is not modifying the caller's variable...

Comment: Also There is already stack/queue in the **Java Collections Framework**, see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto, that class is most likely a homework assignment of some description.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you assign object references to variables.

> I have done all that only my problem is when assigning object A to object B doesn't that mean that A will now points to the address of B?
>
> ```
>    s= newStacks;//shouldnt newStacks get garbage collected
>    //and s gets the new address and attributes of  newStacks?
> ```

It is the other way around since the assignment in Java is from right to left.

Comment: yeah thats what what i mean yet the attribute of the original object being `A`are not changed, if you run my code i think youll understand what im talking about!

Answer (score 0):

"I have done all that only my problem is when assigning object A to object B doesn't that mean that A will now points to the address of B?"

if this is what you meant then:

Stacks A = new Stacks();

Stacks B = A;

Then what this means is that B is now pointing to A.

Answer (score 0):

You're kinda over do it. A stack should consist of a chain of nodes, like an singel-linked list of nodes. I've written an example on this below, see if you can see how it works.

```
public class Stack <E> {

    private StackItem<E> currTop;
    private int size;
    private int max;

    private static class StackItem<E> {
        private E e;
        private StackItem<E> next;
    }


    public Stack(int max) {
        currTop = null;
        size = 0;
        this.max = max;

    }


    public void add(E e){
        if ((size+1) == max) throw new StackOverflowError("Max items in stack is reached");
        StackItem<E> old = currTop;             
        currTop = new StackItem<>();           
        currTop.e = e;                          
        currTop.next = old;                     
        size++;                                

    }


    public E getFirst() {
        if (currTop == null) return null;   
        E output = currTop.e;               
        currTop = currTop.next;             
        size --;
        return output;

    }

    public E showFirst() {
        return currTop.e;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }




}
```

Comment: sorry i am not interested in a different solution, i am however interested in debugging my current one. thanks for the effort anyways